# Installing KloxoMR on Google cloud VM

Tags: server, dns, google-compute-engine, lamp, kloxo

I use google cloud services and specially VM instance to host my web-sites,
I used to KloxoMR, and usually I install it on a fresh Centos 6 or 7 with no problem. About google cloud VM I have no problem in installing Kloxo too, but I cant access to my kloxo control panel using `http://ExternalIP:7778` or `7777`(https) it seems there is a problem with this two systems.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure http/https traffic is allowed on your VM, Firewall is disabled or allows foreign hits and your GCP platform also allows foreign hits.

Comment: http/https traffic is allowed, but i cant disable firewall. how should I allow foreign hits using Console ?

Comment: systemctl stop firewalld
After this, check whether it's disabled or not by : systemctl status firewalld

Comment: I did it but its not working, I got timeout !

Comment: Open ingress ports 7778 & 7777.

Yes, the protocol is http(s), but it is over ports 7777 & 7778 instead of the default 80 & 443, which are the default HTTP/HTTPS ports. ":12345" at the end of a URL is specifying the port number. The HTTP & HTTPS network tags simply open ports 80 & 443 for the instance tagged with them. You can see this in your firewall rules.
Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Also, what is the exact the error message in your browser?

Comment: Milad i opened that ports in google console, i also tried a rule that opens all posts for everyone, but i got Empty response error, i tried other control panels like CWP, Zpanel, webmin,...which are using different ports like 2030,8083 and.... They didn't work! But installing plesk using Google installer works with no problem on port 10000!

Comment: Milad if you have access to GCP, and you have enough credits, please try installing a free linux control panel

Comment: I also talked with google support team, they said that your firewall rules are ok, there is a problem with kloxo probably which they said that is a third party application and any support for that is out of their services

Answer (score 0):

You need setup firewall rules on Google Clould account

```
http add 7778 port
https add 7777 port
Example:
default-allow-http
Entrada
http-server
Intervalos de IP: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:80,7778
Permitir
1000
default-allow-https
Entrada
https-server
Intervalos de IP: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:443,7777
Permitir
1000
```